# Minimizing a Lebesgue integral subject to a single equality constraint

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable, $\mu:=f\lambda$ and $$E(p):=\int_{\{\:p\:>\:0\:\}}\frac1p\:{\rm d}\mu\in[0,\infty]$$ for $\mathcal E$-measurable $p:E\to[0,\infty)$.

> I want to minimize $E(p)$ subject to $$\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers. (I already know the solution. The question really is how we can find it using Lagrange multipliers.)

Unfortunately I'm already failing to come up with a suitable Banach space in which we search the solution. (The main problem being that we can't simply choose an $L^q$-space and $E(p)$ might be $\infty$. I'm not sure, but since I'm willing to assume that there exists at least one $p$ such that $E(p)<\infty$, we might resolve the latter issue somehow.)

Comment: In the general case, the infimal value of $E$ is zero, but there is no $p$ with $E(p) = 0$. Hence, there does not exist a minimizer. Do you have additional assumptions which guarantee the existence of a minimizer?

Comment: @gerw Maybe I'm missing something, but we should be in the sample situation as described here at the beginning of page 4: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-is.pdf. As shown on page 6 the minimizer is $q^\ast=\frac{|f|p}\mu$ (with the notation of the reference). The situation described here shouldn't be different from the situation in the reference, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I would say that the situtation is very different. If you formulate (9.1) in your language, $\mu$ depends on $p$. On the other hand, if you reformulate (9.4), the numerator depends on $p$.

Comment: @gerw In the reference they aim to minimize $$q\mapsto\int\frac{(pf)^2}q\tag1$$ subject to $\int q=1$ (notation from the reference). The integral in $(1)$ can equivalently be thought of as an integral of $\frac1q$ wrt the measure with density $(pf)^2$. So, my $f$ is simply their $(pf)^2$ and the object we're minimizing is the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: One crucial difference is that you integrate only over $\{p > 0\}$, whereas $q > 0$ is required in the reference.

Comment: @gerw Nope, they explicitly allow $q=0$. They should integrate over $\{q>0\}$ as well, but they are not rigorous in notation and exploit that $\{q=0\}$ is a null set (as is $\{p=0\}$ in this question).

Comment: Nope. In Theorem 9.1: "$q(x) > 0$ whenever $f(x)p(x) \ne 0$". The same on page 6: "let $q$ be any density that is positive when $fp \ne 0$".

Comment: @gerw Acually, I'm want to assume the same: $\{f\ne0\}\subseteq\{p>0\}$. However, I don't see how this changes anything, since $\{f=0\}$ is obviously a $\mu$-null set.